# Unity to Android - Simple if statement not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Just tested my game in Unity editor and all works fine:

```
void Update () {

        if (transform.position.y < -3f) {

            Debug.Log ("game over!");
            prepareGame ();


        }

    }
```

All works fine the if is executed when y is below -3 but...

When I export the game and test on android, the if statement never 
gets called!

I debuged the droid version and the value Y is BELOW -3 but still, 
the if never gets called and the game never ends...why?

Comment: I think maybe you can try use `fixupdate` instead of update.

Comment: maybe your prepareGame () code is bad. Post the code in that function

Comment: it works in the editor...and also on the bluestacks android simulaltor, but on actual device...no...https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnmxhl7ewb456eb/prepareCode.txt?dl=0

Comment: You were right, the problem is indeed in the prepareGame function...but it does not crash the app that's why it confused me...

Answer (score 1):

It's best practices not to compare float values.

Solutions:

1) Use Mathf.Approximately(float a, float b) [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

2) Use Mathf.RoundToInt(float f) [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html)

3) Use triggers. This might be more than you need for this solution

I don't have enough rep to link #3 but lookup Collider.OnTriggerEnter(Collider)

Comment: Thanks Im using Int but still it does not work when comparing numbers like 3 < -3...